# Virtualbox not downloading on Kubuntu

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, kubuntu, 64-bit

[image]

Can someone please help me. I have tried many times to download VirtualBox and it has been failing. I use Kubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit. Let me know if you need anymore information. Thank You!  :)

Comment: Not really an answer, but I suggest you use KVM / Virt-manager rather then Vbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still you have alternative way to download virtualbox:-

form **terminal** : `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`

from **installer** : download from virtualbox website [Here!](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)